# How to get data from database using java multithread to send push notification as fast as possible?

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, push-notification

I wanna send push notification to users using java and oracle database.
My android application registration ids saved in oracle database and I want to use java multithread to read data from database and sending push notification as fast as possible. 
I don't want to use any third party applications like Parse or Pusher.
My problem is if multiple threads reads data from the same record the android users may receive more than one notification.
How can i avoid multiple threads reads same record at once. 
It's a huge database.

Comment: 1. You may use Oracle `select for update`  feature. 2. Use dedicated
thread for selecting records then dispatch these records to multiple threads for push notification job.

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing an idea to read data.

---

1. Having row with generated sequence
2. Initiate thread with an INTEGER value naming `THREAD_ID`
3. SELECT query in thread `where sequence % THREAD_ID = 0`
4. Assuming in your huge database you are filtering data by some clause or limiting, though the mod query couldn't affect the performance.

Though it won't read the same data by more than one thread.

---

You can use this technique if it fit in your application.

Comment: You are right, but how to cover all records in this scenario?

Comment: All records means?